# Libgdx how to fix Missing Asset Catalog in 'IOSLauncher.app'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, libgdx, robovm

I get this problem when I upload my app :

> Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in
>   'IOSLauncher.app'.

I am using robovm to create the IPA file here is my info.plist

```
 <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Icon</string>
                <string>Icon-72</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I am using xCode9

Answer (score -1):

here is how I solved it :

Generate Assets.xcassets folder.
Create an empty iOS project with Xcode 9, give it whatever name. Then refer to Assets.xcassets folder in left panel:

[image]

Double click to open it. Xcode creates a default asset catalog named "AppIcon". Select "AppIcon", then add all icon size of your app.

[image]

Close this windows and save project. Then refer to this project's folder in Finder:

[image]

There will be a folder called "Assets.xcassets":

[image]

Open your RoboVM project's folder, then go to the folder where you set to save your iOS assets.
This folder will be like "data", "resource". To know which, just open "robovm.xml" file, there will be a node named "resources", and then it will tell you which folder RoboVM will refer to when building iOS app with given assets.

[image]

In my case, it will be "data" folder, just under my iOS project's folder:

[image]

Copy "Assets.xcassets" folder from the project we just created with Xcode 9 to "data" folder.

Modify your iOS project's "Info.plist.xml" file.
Under "dict" node, add like this:

[image]

Then comment out all the icon info in "CFBundleIcons", you will not use this anymore.

```
<!--key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Icon</string>
                <string>Icon-72</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict-->
```

Comment: Missing many steps.